# hasqueryfilter error in ef core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.created_at.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

produces this error:

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

The created_at property is typed to DateTime.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not to sure what `Created_at` is but it its a regular date Mostly likely your missing beta version of .NET-Core.  if you upgrade to 2.1 this should be fixed.

Comment: I am running 2.1.0-preview1-26216-03

Comment: sorry my fault I think I know the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to get it:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
      .HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<DateTime>(b, "created_at").Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
```

Not sure why Datetime.Today throws the error though.